# Laravel get all traffic over www. domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel, redirect

I want to get all my traffic over `www.domain.com` and not `domain.com`.

How can I do this within Laravel 4? But the problem is, I *don't* want to work with `.htaccess`, because in Laravel I have this:

`.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

But the problem is, when I go to `domain.com/login` it redirects to `www.domain.com/index.php` I don't want that.

How can I fix that the redirects to `www.domain.com/login`?

Comment: You'll need to move the last block that redirects to `www.` up above the rule that redirects trailing slashes.

Comment: How could I be so stupid... Thanks man! This helped me! :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MikeRockett I found the solution!

Solution code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    #redirect from naked url
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```